# Como adicionar uma nova tabela 1:N (um para muitos) em um banco de dados existente via migration laravel?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, table, migrations, chave-estrangeira

Olá! Preciso adicionar uma nova tabela em uma BD já existente. Utilizo o Framework Laravel e gostaria de fazer isso via Migration, porém toda vez que tento dá erro e não sei o que posso estar fazendo de errado.
Eu criei uma Model chamada Cidade que contém o relacionamento com a Model de Bairro:

**Model da Cidade:**

```
public function bairros()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bairro::class, 'tb_cidades_id');
    }
```

**Model do Bairro:**

```
public function cidade()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cidade::class, 'tb_cidades_id');
    }
```

**Migration para Adicionar a Table de Cidades:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tb_cidades', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('cidade', 60);
            $table->string('estado', 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Migration para Adicionar a Foreing Key a Table de Bairros:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('tb_bairros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tb_cidades_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tb_cidades_id')->references('id')->on('tb_cidades');
        });
    }
```

**O erro:**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_xxx`.`#sql-cc0_10`, CONSTRAINT `tb_bairros_tb_cidades_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tb_cidades_id`) REFERENCES `tb_cidades` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `tb_bairros` add constraint `tb_bairros_tb_cidades_id_foreign` foreign key (`tb_cidades_id`) references `tb_cidades` (`id`))

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Suas tabelas já estão com dados? Se sim verifique se em Bairros existe alguma referência a uma cidade inexistente.

Comment: Sim, todas elas. Essa table cidade é nova, ela vai estar zerada e eu vou adicionar os dados via Seeder. Agora na table Bairros não existe nada que interligue ambas as tables, apenas um atributo chamado cidade, mas não tem nada a haver com a nova table.

Comment: Nãomé o que diz a mensagem de erro. `(SQL: alter table tb_bairros add constraint tb_bairros_tb_cidades_id_foreign foreign key (tb_cidades_id) references tb_cidades (id))`. O campo `tb_bairros.tb_cidades_id` referencia `tb_cidades.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução paliativa seria desabilitar as constraints

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('tb_cidades', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('cidade', 60);
            $table->string('estado', 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
```

Alguma constraint no seu banco ta gerando esse erro, ou você refaz ela ou desabilita temporariamente